# Cannot read property of inner function in IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife, self-invoking-function

```
var ag = (function(){
        function update(at){
            console.log('at::'+at);
        }
        return {hike:function(){update(2);}}
})();
```

In this method i am able to access inner function hike() through the reference(ag.hike();).

```
var ag = (function(){
         function update(at){
            console.log('at::'+at);
         }
         return update(2);
})();
```

in the above example i am unable to access same inner update() method even through reference(ag.update(2) or ag.update()).

I read that we cannot read inner property of IIFE. But in the first case i am able to access and for the second case i am unable to access.

What is the difference between the above 2 examples?
and why these two different behaviors? 
Please explain me. sorry for my English.

Comment: In the first snippet you're returning an objcet, which has a method, which is closed over the IIFE. In the second snippet there's no closure, the IIFE returns just a value (which actually is `undefined`).

Comment: `function update(at)` returns undefined .. you return `return update(2);` ... therefore `ag === undefined`

Comment: thanks, but i have read somewhere any inner function can be a closure. So can't we access through closure. sorry if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind`if you want to return a function to be called later with the value of `at` bound to 2;

```
 return update.bind(null, 2);
```

It returns a function which can be called like this

```
ag();// at::2
```

The problem with your approach is that while doing `return update(2);` you are calling the `update` function right away and returning the value returned by `update` function which is `undefined` as you are not returning anything  inside that function.

Comment: Hi @RanjithReddyKeesari, please let me know if the answer is helpful or if you have some doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In the below snippet:

```
var ag = (function(){
   function update(at){
      console.log('at::'+at);
   }
   return { hike: function(){ update(2); } }
})();
```

You're returning an object, whose property `hike` has the reference of the `update` function within it. Here `hike` is a function and hence callable.

In the second snippet:

```
var ag = (function(){
    function update(at){
       console.log('at::'+at);
    }
    return update(2);
})();
```

You're returning the result of `update(2)` and since the `update` function doesn't return anything, `ag` has the value of `undefined`, which is uncallable.

You could try to return the `update` reference and then call it with `2`.

```
var ag = (function(){
    function update(at){
       console.log('at::'+at);
    }
    return update;
})();
ag(2) // at::2
```